# Can you integrate MSpec with the MonoDevelop test runner?

Tags: monodevelop, mspec

Can you integrate MSpec with the MonoDevelop test runner? It's [working in Sharp-Develop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/11/09/MachineSpecifications.aspx). Google says '[nothing](http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=using%20mspec%20with%20monodevelop)' so I'm guessing it's not possible as of the current release (2.8.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So time passes, and someone has actually created a runner for mspec that works with monodevelop.

> MSpecRunner
>   Runner for running Machine.Specifications specs in MonoDevelop

https://github.com/dolittle/MSpecRunner

I've not had time to try it out, but wanted to put it here for completion.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly *possible* since MonoDevelop is open-source, but at this point you'd have to modify the core unit testing addin, you couldn't just drop it in.